# Contract terms are binding as long as services are provided on a mutually agreed-upon basis

Tags: contract-law, business

Context: B2B Contract

If one party chooses to discontinue future service, does this statement void the rest of the contract?

> Contract terms are binding as long as services are provided on a mutually agreed-upon basis.

My Reasoning: Since the services can no longer be provided on a mutual basis, as one party wishes to discontinue service, then the terms of the contract seem to no longer be binding.

Answer (score 1):

### It probably voids the whole agreement right now

What you have is an [agreement to agree](https://definitions.uslegal.com/a/agreement-to-agree/) - these are unenforceable. Technically such an agreement is void for uncertainty.